# MySQL/PHP Grouping results based on date range and user id

Tags: php, mysql

Hello so here is my dilema.  I have 2 tables, one called users and user_betting. Users i was using to innerjoin their name to the results in the link below.  Here is the table structure of user_betting.

```
id
handicapper_id
game_id
sport
date_placed
ML_team
ML_decision
ML_points
ML_awarded
OU_team
OU_decision
OU_points
OU_awarded
SPREAD_team
SPREAD_decision
SPREAD_points
SPREAD_awarded
```

If you browse this page. http://wewatchcappers.com/rankings_full.php?sport=MLB you can see currently I can pull the data for 30 / 60 / 90 days.  However my method of doing so doesn't allow me to sort highest points.  Basically what needs to happen is I need to count the number of times they have the word win / tie / loss in any of the *_decision.  The points will need to be the sum of the *_awarded.  These could be negative and positive numbers.

I believe I will need to input this into an array and then sort it but I do not know the best way to go about this.  Can anyone give me help here?

Here is the current way I have it done.

```
<?php foreach($conn->query("SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN user_betting ON users.id=user_betting.handicapper_id WHERE sport = '$sport' AND date_placed BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW() GROUP BY user_betting.handicapper_id") as $rankings) { ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><a href="<?php echo $rankings['username'];?>"><?php echo $rankings['username']; ?></a></td>
                                <td align="center">

                                <?php       
                                $ml30wins = $conn->query("SELECT count(*) FROM user_betting WHERE sport = '$sport' AND ML_decision = 'win' AND handicapper_id = ".$rankings['handicapper_id']." AND date_placed BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW() ")->fetchColumn(); 
                                $ou30wins = $conn->query("SELECT count(*) FROM user_betting WHERE sport = '$sport' AND OU_decision = 'win' AND handicapper_id = ".$rankings['handicapper_id']." AND date_placed BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW() ")->fetchColumn(); 
                                $spread30wins = $conn->query("SELECT count(*) FROM user_betting WHERE sport = '$sport' AND SPREAD_decision = 'win' AND handicapper_id = ".$rankings['handicapper_id']." AND date_placed BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW() ")->fetchColumn(); 
                                echo $ml30wins+$ou30wins+$spread30wins;
                                ?>
                                </td>
                                <td align="center">
                                <?php       
                                $ml30loss = $conn->query("SELECT count(*) FROM user_betting WHERE sport = '$sport' AND ML_decision = 'loss' AND handicapper_id = ".$rankings['handicapper_id']." AND date_placed BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW()")->fetchColumn(); 
                                $ou30loss = $conn->query("SELECT count(*) FROM user_betting WHERE sport = '$sport' AND OU_decision = 'loss' AND handicapper_id = ".$rankings['handicapper_id']." AND date_placed BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW()")->fetchColumn(); 
                                $spread30loss = $conn->query("SELECT count(*) FROM user_betting WHERE sport = '$sport' AND SPREAD_decision = 'loss' AND handicapper_id = ".$rankings['handicapper_id']." AND date_placed BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW()")->fetchColumn(); 
                                echo $ml30loss+$ou30loss+$spread30loss;
                                ?></td>
                                <td align="center">
                                <?php       
                                $ml30ties = $conn->query("SELECT count(*) FROM user_betting WHERE sport = '$sport' AND ML_decision = 'tie' AND handicapper_id = ".$rankings['handicapper_id']." AND date_placed BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW() ")->fetchColumn(); 
                                $ou30ties = $conn->query("SELECT count(*) FROM user_betting WHERE sport = '$sport' AND OU_decision = 'tie' AND handicapper_id = ".$rankings['handicapper_id']." AND date_placed BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW()")->fetchColumn(); 
                                $spread30ties = $conn->query("SELECT count(*) FROM user_betting WHERE sport = '$sport' AND SPREAD_decision = 'tie' AND handicapper_id = ".$rankings['handicapper_id']." AND date_placed BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW()")->fetchColumn(); 
                                echo $ml30ties+$ou30ties+$spread30ties;
                                ?>
                                </td>
                                <td align="center">
                                <?php 
                                $ml30query = mysql_query('SELECT SUM(ML_awarded) AS ml30_sum FROM user_betting WHERE handicapper_id = '.$rankings['handicapper_id'].' AND date_placed BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW()'); 
                                $ml30row = mysql_fetch_assoc($ml30query); 
                                $ml30sum = $ml30row['ml30_sum'];
                                $ou30query = mysql_query('SELECT SUM(OU_awarded) AS ou30_sum FROM user_betting WHERE handicapper_id = '.$rankings['handicapper_id'].' AND date_placed BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW()'); 
                                $ou30row = mysql_fetch_assoc($ou30query); 
                                $ou30sum = $ou30row['ou30_sum'];
                                $spread30query = mysql_query('SELECT SUM(SPREAD_awarded) AS spread30_sum FROM user_betting WHERE handicapper_id = '.$rankings['handicapper_id'].' AND date_placed BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW()'); 
                                $spread30row = mysql_fetch_assoc($spread30query); 
                                $spread30sum = $spread30row['spread30_sum'];
                                echo round($ml30sum+$ou30sum+$spread30sum,2);
                                ?>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php } ?>
```

Comment: To count, use `COUNT()` - To sum, use `SUM()` - For time differences, use [`diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

Comment: Can I loop through all these for each of the users?  Also to not show anyone that doesn't have any wins / ties / losses

Comment: You can't loop through the functions directly themselves, but using a `foreach` or `while` based on a variable used in conjunction with the query.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT (SUM(LEN(OU_DECISION),LEN(ML_DECISION),LEN(SPREAD_DECISION)) - SUM(LEN(REPLACE(OU_DECISION, 'win', '')),LEN(REPLACE(SPREAD_DECISION, 'win', '')),LEN(REPLACE(ML_DECISION, 'win', ''))))/3`

You want to substract the length of all the texts without the word "win" to the length of all the texts with the word "win".

```
sum of all text - sum of text without "win"
```

That will give you the number of "win" characters you have, which you should divide by 3 to know how many time the word is said.

Comment: Please, elaborate or explain a little more your answer.

Comment: you can also try it out and tell me if it works, I'm prone to errors